# How to find the correlation between two genes and their separate overall survival outcome?

Tags: gene, differential-expression

i am struggling to find the correlation between two isoforms and their survival outcome. i do have a dataset that is a cohort for thousands of genes and am only interesting in two which they should be isofroms to each other. However, i thought the ratio between these two might be a prognostic marker. i need to find a way where i can see if this is possible by interpreting the clinical outcome which is the overall survival. many thanks guys.

**Crossposted: https://www.biostars.org/p/9566172/**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.